# Push token doesn't work on the first launch

Tags: ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, uiapplicationdelegate

We're using push notifications in our application, but we had to handle them in *not standard* way so, we `registerForRemoteNotifications` after we successfully send a new Post. In that case we get the standard `UIAlertView` asking if you want to receive the push notifications from the application. Easy, peasy... After we accept we receive the **push token** in `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` and we just check if token stored locally in `NSUserDefaults` is the same as the one just pushed from `UIApplication` - if they differ we send the new one to the backend and save it in `NSUserDefaults`, but here comes the *magic*.
Push token received from the `UIApplication` doesn't work! I mean, when I query it from HTTP request and use [Houston](https://github.com/nomad/houston) to send push notification from CLI it doesn't deliver.
What's strange when I re-launch the application and my registration code gets called again (this time from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, because push token may change) everything works correctly and I can send push notifications to device and actually receive them.

I'm 100% sure the `registerForNotification` method gets called only one, so I actually have no idea what's going on here...
I'm curious what's going on here. Does the Push Notification Token somehow get expired or whatever even before I use it for the first time? What's the lifecycle?

Comment: did you resolve your problem?

Comment: For us it was a problem on the backend... They weren't saving the correct token, so it turned to be a Russian roulette 